# Vimeo - search description and tags - Pro user, private videos

Tags: php, video, vimeo-api

I am a Vimeo Pro user with my videos set to private so they can only be viewed via a specific IP address. I have created a front end application for displaying only my videos which includes a search function using the Vimeo API.

The search successfully returns my videos based upon their title but will not search my videos’ tags or description. I am using the following PHP code along with Vimeo’s PHP library:

```
$query = 'search term';

$vimeo = new Vimeo\Vimeo($app_id, $app_secret, $token);

//get the video list
$args = array(
    'per_page'      => 5, // 50 is the max
    'page'          => $page,
    'query'         => $query,
    'sort'          => $sort,
    'direction'     => 'desc',
    'filter'        => 'CC'
);
$results = $vimeo->request('/me/videos', $args);
```

**I need to be able to search via tags and description to make my application viable.**

Does anyone know a solution or is this not possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: They do have a search-by-tag method, see [link](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.getByTag)

Comment: Thanks parthunberg. I am using the new API (your link points to the older deprecated API). There is a method of searching by tags put it pulls results from across Vimeo not just my account. For my application it must only search my private videos. As I pointed out above I can search on the title but not tags or description which seems very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default on site search does not search through private videos. Because of this, we offer a less powerful search for Private PRO users. This search does not support description or tags.

We plan on expanding our more powerful search system, but I can not assure a timeframe.

Your best bet at the moment is to index the data in your own search service (such as solr or elasticsearch).